# Receiving Heroku Site Error Message after installing AWS Gemfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku, amazon-s3

[image]OneMonth: Rails Day 25 Issues

After logging in and trying to create a new dot, I receive this message:

> We're sorry, but something went wrong. If you are the application
>   owner check the logs for more information.

(https://agile-springs-9760.herokuapp.com/dots) Although it is loading locally.

I read previously that it could be the version of the AWS Gemfile, but what I bundle installed should support the current version.

GitHub: https://github.com/findingtheway/pin

*I have recently updated my version of Git Bash, due to indicated vulnerabilities.

Comment: Add the log from Heroku to the bottom of your question. Without the log, we can't help you

Comment: I've attached a photo. Thanks!

Comment: This photo doesn't help. It lists failed sign-ins, not what happens when you hit the above URL. Tail the heroku log, find the appropriate action (should be a GET and have the word dots in it), and post that